# Search for keys from an array within values of another array and replace

Tags: php, arrays

There are multiple ways to do this I'm sure. I have an array that looks like this:

```
$map=array(
'ABC'=>'first_three',
'DEF'=>'second_three',
'GHI'=>'third_three'
)

$info=array(
    array('x','XXABCXXXX','x','x','x'),
    array('x','XXXDEFXXXX','x','x','x'),
    array('x','XXXXXXXXXX','x','x','x'),
    array('x','XXXXXXXABC','x','x','x'),
    array('x','XXXXXXXXXX','x','x','x')
)
```

I want to do a find/replace so that the 2nd string in the array will be compared to the keys in $map and if any are found, they'll replace the key with whatever was in the $map.

```
array('x','XXfirst_threeXXXX','x','x','x')
```

I want to loop through $info so:

```
foreach ($info as $i){
    [something with $i[1] and $map]
}
```

What's the most efficient way to do this? Does it use "in_array"?

Comment: `str_replace()` inside the foreach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need `$i` referenced with `&` to use this way:

```
foreach ($info as &$i){
    $i[1] = str_replace(array_keys($map), $map, $i[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($info as $key => $i) {
  foreach($map as $k => $v) {
    // replace the key $k ("ABC") with the value $v ("first_three") in the 2nd element of $info, for each $key
    $info[$key][1] = str_replace($k, $v, $info[$key][1]);
  }
}
```